# self.propertyName vs _propertyName in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I understand the difference between the two: `self.propertyName` uses the accessor method whereas `_propertyName` accesses the instance variable directly.  So as I understand it, the *only* time you *don't* want to use the `self.propertyName` is inside the property's accessor method, since it would cause an infinite loop.  As long as I follow that rule, is it ok, and perhaps good for the sake of consistency, to use self.propertyName every time you need to get/set that property inside a class method?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: Yes. See [Use Accessor Methods to Set Property Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW5) and [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6), so you should refrain from using accessor methods in both `init` methods and `dealloc` methods.

Comment: ahhh dealloc as well, that makes sense. thx!

Comment: "_propertyName accesses the property directly" - well, no, it accesses the underlying *instance variable* directly.

Comment: Also, using the getter/setter is necessary when you're setting a copied or retained object. Simply assigning to the ivar will not retain nor copy the set object, only if you go through the mutator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as setters and getters, you should avoid dot notation in your `init` and `dealloc` methods on the grounds that it's not safe to call published methods on a class that's half constructed or half destroyed.

The particular risk is that a subclass might have added logic into its accessors. If you call the accessor in `dealloc` then you'll call the subclass *after* it's deallocated itself. If you call the accessor in `init` then you'll call into the subclass *before* it's initialsed itself.

Much the same thing can also happen if you have any key-value observers — of you call a setter then they're alerted of the change and given a reference to you regardless of your current state. So it's not even safe if you strictly disallow subclassing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're spot on. Consistency is the most important thing out of all of this. My personal preference is to use the dot notation where ever possible, but use the direct instance variable if required (for example, within getter/setters).

Saying that, you want to be careful if you're in the properties setter method too, as `self.property = val` within `setProperty:` will also call an infinite loop; the solution being `_property = val`.

Answer (score 1):

proper use of properties will further consistency (as said) also allow for better subclassing :)

---

still... in some situations.. e.g. in a threading context where you want stuff to be atomic or so, you gotta fallback to the var